# HTML5, CSS3, SVG - absolute position - relative size and positioning - responsive design

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm wondering if someone has a solution for the following issue:

I'm trying to develop a fluid and responsive webiste that requires svg integration.

My current issue is related to the fact that svg elements needs to maintain aspect ratio and in the same time, to have them fully responsive. See below:

Working fine at this resolution:
[image: Working fine at this resolution]

Wrong positioning:
[image: Broken position]

Here you can find the css:

```
div.body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    background: #39BFBD;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.scene {
  width: 42%;
  height: 65%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}
.scene .inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.scene .inner div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
.scene .inner div svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.scene .inner div.chair {
  width: 11%;
  height: 33%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-11%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-11%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-11%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-11%, 0);
}
.scene .inner div.chair.chair-1 {
  left: 20%;
}
.scene .inner div.chair.chair-2 {
  left: 64%;
}
.scene .inner div.table {
  left: 40%;
  width: 28%;
  height: 23%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-28%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-28%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-28%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-28%, 0);
}
.scene .inner div.coffee {
  width: 5.2%;
  height: 9.7%;
  bottom: 23%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-5.2%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-5.2%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-5.2%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-5.2%, 0);
}
.scene .inner div.coffee.coffee-1 {
  left: 38%;
}
.scene .inner div.coffee.coffee-2 {
  left: 50%;
}
.scene .inner div.floor {
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2%;
  background: #28B3AD;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I've attached a jsfiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/U8j7a/

Comment: I can't see what is the goal and the correct behavior. What is wrong with the second screenshot?

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for not being clear enough.

In the second screenshot, the positioning of the chair elements and the coffee cups. As you can see, they are distanced from the table.